Apache's SSL crash after some time, doesn't serve the SSL certificate
I'm currently experiencing a weird issue with Apache 2.4, after some time (like 1 day), my apache doesn't serve the SSL certificate that is installed in the virtualhost. I have to restart apache in order to make it serve the SSL certificate again. Basically, the browser doesn't detect the ssl certificate and throws some "Insecure connection" error, which indeed disappears when I restart apache.
This is my current virtualhost configuration (I have to hide the server domain) :
<VirtualHost XXX:80>
    ServerName XXX
    Redirect permanent / https://XXX/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost XXX:443>
    DocumentRoot "/home/project/staging/dashboard/build"
    ServerName XXX

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
    LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common

    <Directory "/home/project/staging/dashboard/build">
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.\.\/
        RewriteRule ^ - [F]
    </Directory>

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

There's no errors at all when I restart apache.
And no relevant errors either in apache logs..
I'm adding the logs that's being written when I restart apache:
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:04.051573 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00163: Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.1.1w configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:04.051591 2024] [core:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:18.304163 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 682856:tid 682856] [client 139.59.132.8:43442] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/project/staging/dashboard/build/server-status
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:32.594377 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/openssl (/usr/lib/php/20220829/openssl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/openssl.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/openssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/xsl (/usr/lib/php/20220829/xsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/xsl.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/xsl.so: undefined symbol: dom_node_class_entry)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "curl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "exif" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "fileinfo" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "ftp" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "gd" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "gettext" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "intl" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "mysqli" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "pdo_mysql" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "soap" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module "zip" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:32.932134 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00163: Apache/2.4.62 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.1.1w configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 06 09:35:32.932155 2024] [core:notice] [pid 650835:tid 650835] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

